# Url.Action with protocol is returning a link without domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sendgrid

I'm using Url.Action to generate an absolute URL to send in an email. The link is generated inside a controller.

```
ConfirmLink = Url.Action(
    "ConfirmEmail",
    "Account",
    new { userId = user.Id, code },
    HttpContext.Request.Scheme
)
```

For some reason, in local, I have this result:

```
http://localhost:5102/account/confirm-email?userId=10&code=CfDJ8JH5BJKUsPZDnCLwFc3HSEHfe9Fk00NHiJqk36VbvkDbbV39AI7HY5m9pXVItwYE9%2B9ElTcnBSZiDNQ%2FmO5lx1tSnuvDmhzdzGlCQCfPQVe%2B21Nw03uNuBWoO8HCVivqzfudti579bWiaLW6PuuQQimn449YymVjgV3R36HeQID26jTmAxizDTqOsF1%2FvQc5Zw%3D%3D
```

but I have this result, without the domain/https protocol, in staging/prod:

```
http:///account/confirm-email?userId=10&code=CfDJ8JH5BJKUsPZDnCLwFc3HSEHfe9Fk00NHiJqk36VbvkDbbV39AI7HY5m9pXVItwYE9%2B9ElTcnBSZiDNQ%2FmO5lx1tSnuvDmhzdzGlCQCfPQVe%2B21Nw03uNuBWoO8HCVivqzfudti579bWiaLW6PuuQQimn449YymVjgV3R36HeQID26jTmAxizDTqOsF1%2FvQc5Zw%3D%3D
```

I'm using ASP .NET Core with `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0"`.

Application published to IIS.

Comment: Have you tried without specifying the Protocol?

Comment: @ColinM Still the same problem: `http:///account/confirm-email?userId=8&code=...`

Comment: Does `Url.Action` return the full URL anywhere else, in Views or code?

Comment: @ColinM It works in Views, not in Controller. I also tried with a non-dev environment, and the Url is properly sent. :\

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same issue before and the code below works fine for me.

```
var ConfirmLink = Url.Action(
    "ConfirmEmail",
    "Account",
    new { userId = user.Id, code },
    HttpContext.Request.Scheme,
    HttpContext.Request.Host.Value //HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString()
)
```

or manually

```
var ConfirmLink = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}{Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account")}";
```

Comment: just wanted to point out, the answer above didn't work for some reason, had to modified to make it work:
`Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code }, HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme)`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Host parameter:

```
ConfirmLink = Url.Action(
    "ConfirmEmail",
    "Account",
    new { userId = user.Id, code },
    HttpContext.Request.Scheme,
    HttpContext.Request.Host.Host
)
```

Comment: Can you add debug code and see what is the value of HttpContext.Request.Host.Host in production environment?